# JavaScript code editor

Tags: javascript, code-editor

I need to get JavaScript HTML/CSS/JavaScript code editor plugin (I prefer jQuery plugins) for my CMS. I don't need WYSIWYG editor. I need editor where you can see HTML/CSS/JavaScript. I was just thinking if there was any plugin for this, because implementing my own would be very hard work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367099/best-online-code-editor-with-a-textarea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [markItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) and [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) may suit you.

Comment: thanx, CodeMirror seems to most suitable for my needs!

Comment: codemirror does seem better, based on the demo, markitup seems to modify code, which can be bad (eg: automatically converts tabs to four spaces)

Answer (score 1):

[markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/) is a great jQuery based markup editor with html support.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that i have seen/used are CuteEditor (paid solution) and FCKEditor (free solution, or it was free at the time i saw it). We went with cute editor int he end because the feature set was far more robust and they offer better support.

FCKeditor - ckeditor(dot)com/

CuteEditor - http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET%2BWYSIWYG%2BEditor/

Comment: forgive the first link being kinda weird, i just signed up and they wont let me post you 2 links, so replace the (dot) with a "."